# Text Ubuntu logo on boot

Tags: boot, plymouth, 14.10

I recently updated my graphics card and drivers on my machine, however, after the successful upgrade, I found that the traditional Ubuntu logo had been replaced with a text logo in a console-like serif font. This also coincided with a change in the screen resolution.

I am hoping that somebody may be able to tell me how to reverse this change.

This is the result of update-alternatives --config default.plymouth:

```
  Selection    Path                                                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
* 0            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       auto mode
  1            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth   99        manual mode
  2            /lib/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       manual mode
```

Thanks for any help.

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the graphics drivers failed to load at boot, or `nomodeset` has been enabled, making the kernel not load the graphics card drivers. Check your boot settings.