# Ubuntu 18.10 using text-based plymouth theme after updates

Tags: plymouth

I had updated my ubuntu 18.10 installation, however it has started using the text based plymouth theme instead of the graphical theme. Does anyone know why this is, and if so how to fix it?

I have tried looking around and nothing I have found is that readable, so if someone could make a script, that would probably be great.

Comment: This might help https://askubuntu.com/questions/542666/

Comment: You mean boot messages are showing up: https://askubuntu.com/questions/248/how-can-i-show-or-hide-boot-messages-when-ubuntu-starts?

Comment: @pomsky I believe OP is referring to something like [this](http://i.imgur.com/w9vgl.jpg)